# Numpy: efficiently multiply arrays at location based on condition

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following four arrays with identical shape:

```
a = np.array([12, 6, 7])
b = np.array([2, 3, 3])
c = np.array([5, 4, 9])
d = np.array([15, 22, 28])
```

As long as the condition `num > 20` is met for each element in `d`, I want to multiply `a` by `b` and replace the values in `c` with the individual result of that multiplication. So, `c` would be equal to `[5, 18, 21]`.

My attempt:

```
c[d > 20] = a[d > 20] * b[d > 20]
```

Is there any way to implement this more efficiently for large arrays?

Comment: `mask=d>20`, and then use that in the equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) too:

```
c = np.where(d > 20, a * b, c)
```

which places `a * b`'s values in the output where `d > 20` and `c`'s values otherwise.

timing: (setup from other answer)

```
a = np.random.randint(50, size=10000)
b = np.random.randint(50, size=10000)
c = np.random.randint(50, size=10000)
d = np.random.randint(50, size=10000)

%timeit np.where(d > 20, a * b, c)
28.2 µs ± 504 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: I'm surprised that this is so much faster than the `np.multiply` version.

Answer (score 3):

The expression, `c[d > 20] = a[d > 20] * b[d > 20]` is computing the result of `d > 20` three times. You can improve that by doing

```
mask = d > 20
c[mask] = a[mask] * b[mask]
```

To improve further, you can use the fact that [`np.multiply`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html) is a [`ufunc`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html#ufunc). This means that is has a [`where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html#optional-keyword-arguments) option to determine where the calculation will actually be done without making any temp arrays, and an [`out`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html#optional-keyword-arguments) option to emplace the output:

```
np.multiply(a, b, where=d > 20, out=c)
```

A quick `timeit` shows that the second option is indeed approximately 2.5x faster (on my machine at least):

```
a = np.random.randint(50, size=10000)
b = np.random.randint(50, size=10000)
c = np.random.randint(50, size=10000)
d = np.random.randint(50, size=10000)

%%timeit
m = d > 20
c[m] = a[m] * b[m]
172 µs ± 460 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit np.multiply(a, b, where=d > 20, out=c)
66.4 µs ± 219 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

An even more important lesson to be had here is that this particular operation will almost certainly not be your bottleneck.